# Stern for kubernetes pod logs not working

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I installed stern on mac with brew. https://github.com/wercker/stern

When I run stern pod-query there is no output. the cursor keeps on blinking in the terminal. What's wrong here?

I tried stern pod-query -n , stern service -> all with same result.

Answer (score 1):

it worked. i used :

> stern ".*" --tail -1 -n

thanks to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935566/6492560